# output_add_rewrite_var doesn't rewrite URL

Tags: php, url-rewriting

`output_add_rewrite_var()`

As documented [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.output-add-rewrite-var.php)

> This function adds another name/value pair to the URL rewrite mechanism. The name and value will be added to URLs (as GET parameter) and forms (as hidden input fields).

So the following code is supposed to do the trick

```
<?php
output_add_rewrite_var('var', 'value');

echo '<a href="test.php">link</a>'; 

echo '<form action="test.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="var2" />
</form>';
?>
```

On `form` it works fine, and add a hidden field. But the URL(`a` tag) is still the same.

`http://localhost/test.php`

I'm expecting

`http://localhost/test.php?var=value`

How to fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure it will rewrite your link (a) until you actually perform a request (i.e click it) - it would then append the extra var...?

Comment: Seems to be a version issue https://3v4l.org/GbZg9 maybe `url_rewriter.tags` or `url_rewriter.hosts` difference?

Comment: Maybe a legit bug not sure.

Comment: What happens when you click the link - does it take you (rewrite) to the URL with extra var?

Comment: @stuart No, it doesn't

Comment: The ini settings will default, you may need to change one.  Do `echo ini_get('url_rewriter.tags')` See the diff here https://3v4l.org/H017D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that if you're using PHP >= 7.1.0 the default tag in `url_rewriter.tags` is `form`.

So what you're gonna have to do is change this line in `php.ini` file:

`;url_rewriter.tags`

To:

`url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,form=,fieldset="`

> Note: The semicolon at the beginning of the line must be removed